# maximum number of threads per block

Tags: cuda, gpu

i have the following information:

```
Maximum number of threads per block:           512
Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
```

does this mean that the maximum number of threads in a 2d thread block is 512x512 which gives me a 262144 threads in every block?
if yes, then is it a good practice to have this number of threads in a a kernel of minimum 256 blocks?

Comment: Yes, it is confusing that they use 512x512x64 terminology, stating for example [512,512,64] as maximum dimensions would be much less confusing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it means that the maximum threads per block is 512,

You can decide how to lay that out over [1 ... 512] x [1 ... 512] x [1 ... 64].

For instance 16x16 would be ok in 2D.

As for the deciding on the size of the block, lots of things come into consideration, like the amount of memory a block needs and how big a half-warp is on the hardware (I don't remember if its always 16 on Nvidia hardware).

Comment: thank you for the clarification. so if considering i have an array of size 1024 and only 512 threads i need to loop over the rest of the array. something like:

Comment: @lina: what exactly do you mean by loop over? What does your code do? you would usually set up your code to run in a number of blocks.

Comment: @lina, that would work.. but I think you wanna have more than one block.

Answer (score 1):

No, that means that your block can have 512 maximum X/Y or 64 Z, but not all at the same time. In fact, your info already said the maximum block size is 512 threads.
Now, there is no optimal block, as it depends on the hardware your code is running on, and also depends on your specific algorithm.