# Threads per block in CUDA 7

Tags: cuda, gpu

I read in '*Programming massively parallel processors (2nd ed)* that

> Each thread block can have up to 1024 threads in CUDA 3.0 and later. Some earlier CUDA versions allow only up to 512 threads in a block

I recently downloaded the CUDA 7.0 toolkit and want to know if the above information is relevant in nowday's version.

It also seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6612935/4224575) question has an outdated info (it was already outdated in 2012 when the mentioned book was published)

Comment: I'm fairly sure it doesn't say that

Comment: @talonmies  I may be missing a greater point (I've just started to struggle with CUDA) but page 54 footnote 7 is quoted as shown in the book.

Comment: Yeah I just found that. It is awfully written. The number of threads isn't tied to the CUDA version, it is tied to the CUDA compute capability. The fact that CUDA 3 and compute capability 2.0 hardware came along at about the same time doesn't make them the same thing

Comment: @talonmies Thnx for your contribution! it helped me better understand the answer by Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA 7 only supports CUDA devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher.  All such devices can support up to 1024 threads per block.

The 512 number pertains to devices of compute capability 1.x, and such devices are no longer supported by CUDA 7.

Note that compute capability and CUDA version are two different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up how many threads per block your GPU supports with the `cudaGetDeviceProperties` function: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int nDevices;

  cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
  for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
    printf("Device Number: %d\n", i);
    printf("  Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
    printf("  Max threads per block: %d\n", prop.maxThreadsPerBlock);
  }
}
```

This code was adapted from http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-query-device-properties-and-handle-errors-cuda-cc/